# SQL queries or php code?

Tags: php, sql, optimization

Hello i am in a delima
Suppose that i have 50 products in a category and i want to get all the features of my products...
Ofcourse a SQL join wont help because joining would return product info many times!

So here is the question.. what is better
**PLAN A**
Get all the products' features in category with one SQL query  and then iterate with php each feature and put it in Product.

**PLAN B**
For each product get the features by calling a query

Other solutions accepted!

## EDIT

My table schema outline is..
A table Product which has product info(per row)
A table features which has features (feature id )
A table for features' values
And a table that has Products with their features and values

Comment: you should post more on your schema. How are your tables organized?

Comment: Yes, please update your question with your schema.   A join may be actually be useful, depending on how exactly data is organised, and what exactly you are trying to get out of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM products P,  ". //don't use star, make sure no fields are overwritten
         INNER JOIN products_to_features PTF on P.id = PTF.project_id
         INNER JOIN features F F.id = PTF.feature_id
         ORDER BY P.id";
$r = mysql_query($sql1, $conn);

$arr = array();
$lastProductId = -1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
   if ($row[p_id] != $lastProductId)
   {
       $lastProductId = $row['p_id'];
       $arr['p_id'] = array('productName' => $row['p_name'], 
                            'productPrice' = $row['p_price'],
                            'productFeatures' = array(),
                             //other fields from product table);
   }
   $arr['p_id']['productFeatures']['f_id'] = array('featureName' => $row['f_name'], blah...);
}
```

I don't know your fields obviously, and you may want to join on feature_values so that will be more work.  You can do keys/values different (ie - product names as keys.  Feature-name as keys with feature-value as values, whatever you want)  but the point is this is doable (and recommended) in one query.

Comment: Thank you for your time.. There is an extra table for feature VALUES..  Would you might telling me if i have to do a seperate query?Thanks again

Comment: no, you still don't its just one more join  i'm not really sure what your table looks like, but i get the impression your products-to-features-to-feature-values table is unnecessary (if thats what it is).  there should be a many to many between products and feature values.  feature values are an instance of a type of feature.  (ie - feature 'flavor' feature value 'strawberry').  once the query is done, just add the new values to #arr in similar fashion.  you may want to have each feature be a key for its respective value

Answer (score 2):

Not Plan B.

Whatever you do this can and should be done with one or at most two total queries (one for headers, one for correctly sorted list of features + id column).  Whether that query is Plan A or some unmentioned Plan C depends on your exact table structure, which isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the less database queries you have to make, the better. It greatly depends on your table structure, but I'd go with Plan A.

Answer (score 0):

A query inside a loop will greatly degrade performance of your application. Avoid it at all cost.

Show us the schema. There's a strong possibility a single SQL query will solve your problem.